# Can't achieve 1cm unit scale, it's always larger

Tags: units

I have the default settings for everything, and in the scene I went to set up units to metric, 1.000 and centimeters, but the grids are 100cm large and if I move an object with the snap to increment, it snaps to 100cm moves or 10cm if I snap with the shift button as well. If I set the unit scale to 100.00000, it shows the grids of world much smaller, but when I move the object, it again says 100cm, even though I barely moved the object. I just want it to snap increment to 1cm and for it to really be 1cm.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to do for precise snapping:

1. Use Orthographic View, *View > Perspective/Orthographic*, <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>
2. Use Top/Side/Front view, *View > Viewpoint*, Shortuct: <kbd>~</kbd>
3. Zoom in (grid scale changes)

[image]